# "Indeed!" for exclamation

Tags: expressions, traduction

I was wondering what the French translation of "indeed" would be, as a one-word exclamation

> What a beautiful goal!
>
> Indeed!

Would it be "en effet" or "effectivement"?

> Quel beau but!
>
> En effect! / Effectivement!

Comment: Do you consider "en effet" as a one-word exclamation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Indeed" is quite formal in English so to keep the same tone, a good translation would be:

- En effet !

In casual spoken French, you are more likely to hear:

- Oui !
- C'est vrai !
- Absolument !

and other similar replies, including even:

- Tout à fait, Thierry !

Answer (score 2):

Without irony, you can use

> effectivement

or

> en effet

It seems to me that the first one denotes a little higher language level, and is  used more rarely in casual conversations. But this highly depends on the tone.

A modified version, close in pronunciation, is written:

> anéfé

and is being used too, from the gimmick of a caricature of famous persons in TV shows ([see here for instance](http://www.tayo.fr/anefe--definition-aide.php)).

Other options could be possible, like

> Carrément !

or

> Tu m'étonnes
>
> C'est clair

Similar expressions in English include:

> I'd say
>
> You bet
>
> Too right
>
> Tell me about it

Do not forget the space before the
`!` sign in French.

If you use it with some irony or doubt, you could say:

> Vraiment ?
>
> Eh bien !

Comment: ...another variant you might want to add, since you started a catalog : *Grave !* (casual register)

Comment: @Romain VALERI C'est trop ça ! (heard from my teenage cousin)

Comment: Indeed is formal register. Many of the ones in the list above are slang.